# Have a local codebase but remote database in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wamp, mamp

In our team, I used to be the only developer, coding directly on our remote dev server but we're hiring more developers so we have a need to move the codebase to our local machines so we don't encounter any file collisions.

However, even though I want to use a local codebase, I don't want to use a local database. Syncing the database seems like a hassle and is to be honest not really needed. So we're sticking to multiple codebases, but one database.

**How can I run Wordpress on my local machine, while still using our remote server database? How do I set this up in MAMP?**

I'm kind of new in setting up servers/ports/databases etc so it's not my strong suite. The problem which I don't know how to get around is the urls.

For instance, our WP sites have the url format:

- site1.portal.dev
- site2.portal.dev

When I type these URLs I want the **codebase** to be local but the **database** to be our remote dev server.

Answer (score -1):

Update the config to point to the remote database. Job done.

As long as the configuration of that database allows you to connect to it, it's very simple.

An example of [updating the wordpress config](http://premium.wpmudev.org/manuals/wpmu-manual-2/creating-and-editing-your-wp-config-php-file/)

Comment: It's not that simple. Wordpress has the site urls as options in its database tables. I don't even know what URL to type to get to my local WP sites because of this.

Answer (score -1):

I work in a multi-developer team. I've found that the best option is to have a full local environment.

We use wp-migrate-db pro for copying the dev database down locally. Once configured (per site) it takes a minute to grab the latest copy from dev.

Having this separation allows your team to make changes for their local development efforts (such as entering bad data, test pages, posts etc) without affecting other developer efforts.

This approach also works well for working with developers of various skill levels...and helps to reduce bigger issues that you may come across later on.

Answer (score -1):

Using your `site1.portal.dev` should work, as the site_url and home_url. When you click on a link in your dev portal, it will continue to use `site1.portal.dev`, as WordPress thinks your site resides there. The database just holds the information, it doesn't matter where it resides.

You can connect to your remote mysql instance by providing the correct host, username, password. Usually it would be `localhost`, but in your case, you will want whatever the IP/DNS address for the machine that is hosting your mysql server is.

You can test the mysql connection with

`mysql <database> -h <host> -u <username> -p`

add `-P <port>` if your mysql server is listening on a different port.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question, I just post the answer I found that works for me in case anyone is looking for the solution of "How can I run Wordpress on my local machine, while still using our remote server database"

- Install WordPress on your server (http://yourdomain.com)
- Configure it with your database
- Make sure whitelisting your local machine IP in "Remote MySQL" within your server's hosting panel
- Pull down the entire WordPress directory onto your local machine
  into a project folder
- Add project folder to MAMP or your local web server app of choice
  (make a note of your Server Name)
- Open your LOCAL copy of wp-config.php Change 'DB_HOST' to
  'yourdomain.com'
- And add the following just above 'require_once(ABSPATH .
  'wp-settings.php'); in wp-config.php file

> define('WP_CACHE', true); $currenthost = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; $mypos = strpos($currenthost, 'localhost'); if ($mypos === false) { define('WP_HOME','http://yourdomain.com'); define('WP_SITEURL','http://yourdomain.com'); } else { define('WP_HOME','http://localhost'); define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost'); }

- Replace each instance of 'localhost' with your 'Server Name' in MAMP. (localhost is default)

Source URL: https://coderwall.com/p/ck8v4a/remote-database-with-local-wordpress-instance